# Getting entities which date is between of requested dates in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

As the title suggested, how can I get the result of this query:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->where('p.sellDate > '.$startDate->format('Y/m/d'))
    ->andWhere('p.sellDate < '.$endDate->format('Y/m/d'))
    ->getQuery();
```

currently no result is given back. I've changed this code many times but didn't get the currect result.

Comment: Have you tried with `->where('p.sellDate > :startDate')`, `->andWhere('p.sellDate < :endDate')` , `->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)`, `->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)`?

Comment: yes, then I'm getting `Attempted to call an undefined method named "getResult" of class "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder".`

Comment: well, it was just fool of me! I forget to `getQuery`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let Doctrine sort out the date objects with:

```
    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.sellDate > :startDate')
        ->andWhere('p.sellDate < :endDate')
        ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
        ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
        ->getQuery()
    ;

    $sells = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

As @geoB suggested, there was just this answer:

```
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Entity');

        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->where('p.sellDate > :startDate')
            ->andWhere('p.sellDate < :endDate')
            ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
            ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
            ->getQuery()
        ;

        $sells = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: If that works for you, I can write it up as an answer so you can get some points by accepting it.  Or you can accept your own answer without the 2 points.  Your choice.

Comment: why not... :) write it up